# How do I add validation to a GridView field?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have gridview as follows:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvOverrideData" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="LightGreen" Width="800" OnRowEditing="OverrideGrid_OnRowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="OverrideGrid_OnRowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="OverrideGrid_RowUpdating">
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="LightGray" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Path">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# GetOverrideTemplatePath(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Path").ToString())
                %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" HeaderText="File Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Extension" HeaderText="File Extension" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FileType" HeaderText="File Type" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Iteration" HeaderText="Iteration" />
        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link" ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true"
        ShowCancelButton="true" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I would like to validate the `FileType` field, so that it only accepts an InDesign, XML, CorelDraw, StaticImage file type, where the extension should be one of

> .indd, .tif, .wmf, .idms, .eps, .pdf, .xml, .inds, .emf, .jpg, .cdr, .gif, .ai, .u01

How can I perform this validation check when a user adds/edit?

Comment: Show your edit template or the form and control where you want to apply validation.

Comment: I cant use edit template specified by my client

Answer (score 0):

You can add validate `before you bind with DataSource`

```
var expression = "FileType == '.indd' OR FileType == '.tif' OR ..... ";
DataRow[] foundRows;
// Use the Select method to find all rows matching the filter.
var foundRows = table.Select(expression);
```

You can also Bind with `DataView` and `filter` on your `DataView`

```
var dataView = new DataView(YourDataTable);
dataView.RowFilter = "FileType == '.indd' OR FileType == '.tif' OR .....";
YourGridView.DataSource = dataView ;
```